# Вылетает приложение с ошибкой Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, исключения

Код ошибки:

```
Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.quuux.sack.Sack
com.pro.data.Favorites.load (Favorites.java:22)
com.pro.HeadspaceApplication.onCreate (HeadspaceApplication.java:65)
android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1007)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4541)
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative (XposedBridge.java)
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod (XposedBridge.java:631)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:151)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1381)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:110)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5292)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:824)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:640)
de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main (XposedBridge.java:132)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

в build.gradle добавлена библиотека:

**compile 'org.quuux.sack:sack:0.1'**

библиотека используется в одном из моих классов:

```
public static void load() {
        try {
            Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).load(new Sack.Listener<String[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(final Sack.Status status, final String[] favorites) {
                    favoriteUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
                    if (favorites == null)
                        return;
                    favoriteUrls.addAll(Arrays.asList(favorites));
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Не пойму что не так и чего не хватает на некоторых устройствах пользователей. Почему у одних работает, у других нет. Версия андроид моя - 7.0, у пользователя которого крашит - 4.4.2...
Приложение работает, ошибок не выдает., но некоторые пользователи отписались, что у них сразу крашит после запуска. Код ошибки взял с логов именно этих пользователей, у которых краш.

строчка 22:
c метода `onCreate()`
...

```
Favorites.load();
```

...

строчка 65 этого метода `Favorites.load();`:

```
Sack.open(String[].class, getFavoritesPath()).load(new Sack.Listener<String[]>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(final Sack.Status status, final String[] favorites) {
                    favoriteUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
                    if (favorites == null)
                        return;
                    favoriteUrls.addAll(Arrays.asList(favorites));
                }
            });
```

Как я понял исключение вызвать на ранней версии андроида нельзя? или как то по другому нужно (вариант с try catch exception e) не пройдёт..?

Comment: Вы уверены что ошибка не из инструментального теста?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, то есть? логи ошибки взял с  firebase Crash Reporting. Проблема у пользователей с 19,18,17,15 уровнем API . Так например у меня с моим android oc 7.0 все работает и не крашится. Не пойму что может быть причиной краша. У меня ошибка которая есть в логах, уходит в исключение как и положено. и приложение дальше функционирует.

Comment: С инструментальным тестом я похоже поторопился с выводами :) Приведите, пожалуйста, весь build.gradle модуля.

Comment: проблему решил уже переносом всего класса из подключенной библиотеки к себе в приложение, создав отдельный класс.

Comment: Если проблему решил, то напиши об этом в вопросе с пометкой РЕШЕНИЕ: